# Dragging MKAnnotationView immediately

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkannotation, mkannotationview

When you set the draggable property of an MKAnnotationView, the default behavior seems to be:

1) user taps the annotation

2) user drags the annotation

Is is possible to combine this into one, so the user can drag the annotation without tapping it first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this source code http://www.github.com/digdog/MapKitDragAndDrop I have tried this code in simulator and it is working fine

Comment: I was actually using the same code. Anyway, the solution is to set the MKAnnotationView's 'selected' property to yes when it's created.

Comment: @cannyboy: Your hint, to set `selected` to yes, is the solution. It deserved a separate answer that should be the accepted solution!